# Axios POST request, body data specifically pass not being recoginized

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

Hi I am trying to do a POST request and I need to pass in these two fields for it to work.

[image: body data]

POST request parameters are placed in the body.

This is what I have right now:

```
                axios.post('http://deviceIP:8080/person/create', {
              pass: "123456",
              person: {
                "age": 42,
                "imgBase64": base64,
                "name": name,
                "prescription": null,
                "sex": sex,
                "type": 3,
                "vipID": vip_id
              }
            },
              {
                "headers": {

                  "content-type": "application/json",

                },
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
```

I get an error back saying "Please enter the pass password field". I suspect it is because pass is being sent in as a JSON as well, so how I would I send it as just a string type. I am trying to implement what is given in this doc,https://germforce.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/MIPS-Smart-Pass-LAN-Interface-API-Documentation.pdf

Please help!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for whatever it is you're trying to connect to because it is not clear what the format of the data should be from just that one diagram.  For example, what content-type is the overall body supposed to be?

Comment: "string" isn't an encoding type. What does the API expect?

Comment: Have you [looked at the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)?

Comment: The second argument being given to `post` is not json.  It's an object.  JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a String.

Comment: Axios will automatically serialize the second parameter to JSON as well as set the content type header. Probably a mismatch with what the API suspects.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it to work! This is what I did, hope it helps others trying to do the same thing:

```
            const person = JSON.stringify({
              age:42,
              imgBase64:base64,
              name:name,
              prescription:null,
              sex:sex,
              type:3,
              vipID:vip_id
            });
            
            var params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('pass', '123456');
            params.append('person', person);

            axios.post('http://deviceIP:8080/person/create', params,
              {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
              )
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I vaguely remember dealing with this problem before with axios. Could you try bundling your "pass" and "person" into one object called "data" like so and tell me if it works better.

```
let data = {
    "pass": "123456",
    "person": 
    {
        "age": 42,
        "imgBase64": base64,
        "name": name,
        "prescription": null,
        "sex": sex,
        "type": 3,
        "vipID": vip_id
    }
}

axios.post('http://deviceIP:8080/person/create', data) {}
```

You will need to change your API a bit to implement this. Here is what it should look like.

```
router.post("http://deviceIP:8080/person/create", (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body) // The entire data object
    console.log(req.body.age) // 42

}
```

Comment: 1) This isn't any different from what OP has already and 2) there isn't any reason why they would need to use callbacks instead of promises.